# Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a seemingly simple operator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I would be very thankful for any hints concerning the finding the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions $f(x)$  of the following operator defined on the segment $[0,2\pi]$:
$$
-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V\cos mx,
$$
$f(x)$ being infinitely differentiable on the whole segment $[0,2\pi]$ and being subject to the boundary conditions 
$$
\forall n\ge0:\quad f^{(n)}(2\pi)=f^{(n)}(0).
$$
$V$ is a real constant, $m$ is a positive integer number.

Comment: I'm wondering if a Fourier series (complex form?) approach is ideal here. Trigonometric potentials are a bit of a pain to work with.

Comment: I tried it, but don't see how to terminate the resulting series.

Comment: I've found out that for $m=2$ the equation is known as Mathieu's differential equation. If anybody knows the name for its generalization for arbitrary integer $m$ please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't have to terminate. But did you manage to find conditions for eigenvalues?

Comment: No, I did not. Do you have some idea?